# Creating a foreign key in MySQL produces error:

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

I'm trying to create a foreign key on a table in MySQL and I'm getting a strange error that there seems to be little info about in any of my searches.

I'm creating the key with this (emitted from mysql workbench 5.2):

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`appointment` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_appointment_CancellationID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`CancellationID` ) REFERENCES `db`.`appointment_cancellation` (`ID` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `FK_appointment_CancellationID` (`CancellationID` ASC) ;
```

at which point I get the error:

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`alarmtekcore`., CONSTRAINT `FK_lead_appointment_CancellationID` FOREIGN KEY (`CancellationID`) REFERENCES `lead_appointment_cancellation` (`)

I've checked [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,103787,220080#msg-220080)

but there's no data in the table.

Comment: When you say there's no data - do you mean the `appointment_cancellation` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply a foreign key constraint on a column with pre-existing data that doesn't already exist in the parent table.

If you run the following to populate the appointment_cancellation table, you should be able to apply the foreign key afterwards:

```
INSERT INTO appointment_cancellation
SELECT DISTINCT a.CancellationID
  FROM appointment
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly; the appointment_cancellation table is a new addition to the DB (and has no records). In the appointment table, all values for CancellationID are null (default).

Comment: @SnOrfus: A record has to exist in `appointment_cancellation`, even if the value is null - that's what a foreign key constraint is.  It ensures that the only values that can exist in the child, are already present in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The two fields - `appointment`.`CancellationID` and `appointment_cancellation`.`ID` - need to be exactly the same type. If one is INT and the other is INT UNSIGNED, you'll get this error.

Comment: Thank you for your input, that was one of the first things I checked (that exact scenario has happened to me in the past).